# HOW to open photo in iphone fb app from other app using fb:// url

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to set a QR code link that showing me a photo uploaded into a new album in Facebook by a remote script.

I saw this page:  [AKOSMA](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook)

I then added fb://photo/id to my qrcode generator script

On Android, the URL works!
on iPhone it loads the Facebook app and loads a white page with no photos.

What URL am I supposed to use?
I tried some other URLs that I read about in the link above, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure there is a Facebook iOS url scheme that supports this?  You shouldn't assume that the iOS and Android apps have the same features

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem it's possible. I tried in may ways!
At the moment I am linking to the photo in mobile Safari: @"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=%@"